# Different names for "function"

Tags: functions, terminology

Quoting a book, "functions can also be named: 
Mappings,
Transformations,
Operators,
Arrows or 
Morphisms"

I have the idea that these different names are used depending on different contexts. But I would like to listen to more precise opinions about this...